# Possible negative connotation question on constructed word

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

I'm a native Spanish speaker. A long time ago, I came out with the name *Phonify* for a product related to mobile services, text messaging, etc.

It came as a good name in Spanish as it is easy to remember.

However, when I was thinking of extending this name for worldwide audience I noticed that the constructed word *phonify* is very close to the word *phony*, and by just how it sounds phonetically it made me think if the name phonify may sound like the act of amplifying/making phoniness! which is of course not what I'm intended to do. It would be a very unfortunate name if that is the case.

I don't know if this line of reasoning is the one a native english speaking person would do or it is absolutely clear that the name is in reference to the word phone, even if it sounds *fōnē-fy* and not *fōn-fy* and therefore a safe name to use for the product.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: In some contexts it might be clear that it's a reference to telephones, or to phonics, but when I read *phonify* the first meaning that came to mind was *make phony*, just like *uglify* means *make ugly* or *fancify* means *make fancy*.

Comment: Thanks. That may explain why I haven't seen an american startup with this name already and everything I've seen using the word phonify comes from non-english speaking countries.

Comment: I think your question is very well posed and interesting. Give us more.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by this: there is already a company "Phonify" that does this. Its European base seems to have adopted the name **Mobivity**, a brand name of Phonify B.V., Amsterdam. https://mobivity.co/uk/terms-and-conditions/